# get the attachmentnames out of a form with 2 RTF fields

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I have a form with 2 rich text fields.(for exmaple rtf1 and rtf2)

In each field the user will upload 1 attachment.

For each field I would like to store the attachment name into another field(for exmaple name1 and name2).

When I use **@Subset(@AttachmentNames;1)** in the form for name1 I get the name of the attachment of rtf1.
When I use the same for name2 I get the name of rtf1 again what is not what I want.

Eventually if there's a way to do it with ssjs instead of dooing it in the form, that would be good also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you cannot utilize a simple formula here. Instead you can access the corresponding RTF via SSJS, get all embeddedobjects (even if there is only one attached) and get the name of it to store in your text field. Something like that should work:

Value of your text field, assuming your datasource is named document1:

```
try {
    var rtf:NotesRichTextItem = document1.getDocument().getFirstItem("rtf1");
    var eos:java.util.Vector = rtf.getEmbeddedObjects();
    for(x=0; x<eos.size(); x++){
        var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eos.elementAt(x);
        return eo.getName();
    }
} catch(e) {}
```

Not tested, YMMV

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code on a xpage to get the attachment names of an specified richtext item

```
var db:NotesDatabase=session.getCurrentDatabase();
var doc:NotesDocument=db.getDocumentByUNID(....);
var valString:String = "";

if (doc.hasItem('rtf1')){
var nrt:NotesRichTextItem=doc.getFirstItem('rtf1');
if (nrt!=null){
    var eos:java.util.Vector = nrt.getEmbeddedObjects();
      if (eos.isEmpty()) {
        valString = 'Nothing found';
      } else {
          var v;
        for (v = 0;v < eos.size();v++){
        var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eos.get(v);
        valString = valString + eo.getName() + ' - ' ;
    }
}
}
return valString;
}
```

The code is taken from http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/DominoHerald/entry/august_20_2011_5_06_pm?lang=de

Maybe use a try/catch around the code snippet